# Python Serial Communication script issues (in Visual Studio)

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I'm currently trying to set up communication between an Arduino UNO and a PC via a serial/USB connection using Python on a Windows PC.

**The goal** is to start a video on a laptop when the Arduino tells it to.

I found a guide online which lead me to the code below but Visual Studio 2017 is just showing errors seemingly at random everywhere. A lot of it seemed to come from the imports and VS's IntelliSense messing up (which I believe is fixed now).

So currently when I'm running the program it's getting stuck at the **ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600, timerout=0)** Line with the error that "name 'port' is not defined" Any idea why that is happening?

I'm unsure if that is the core issue since every time I'm making changes a lot of "unexpected token" and "indent" errors appear for *port*, *newline*, *print* and *ser* (completely at random)

```py
import serial, os, time, serial.tools.list_ports

    cmd = '"C:\\Users\\Josef\\Desktop\\PYTHON_PlayVideo\\PYTHON_PlayVideo\\Video1.mp4" -f --fullscreen --play-and-exit'

    for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports():
      sp = str(p)
      #if (sp.find('COM5') != -1):
      if (sp.find('Arduino') != -1):
          flds = sp.split()
          port = flds[0]
          print(port)

    ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600, timeout=0)

    while 1:
      try:
        line = ser.readline()
        if (line):
          print (cmd)
          os.system(cmd)
      except:
        pass
      time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: 1. Personally, I prefer PyCharm over VS as it makes life simple.
2. The `port` variable is under an `if` condition, so the condition has to be true for the variable to initialize. Does the `print(port)` gives any output?

Comment: i don't think it printed anything, i might try hardcoding which port to use. sp is being set to something along the lines of "COM5 ...." which is the same serial port that shows up in the arduino program. but i don't know the exact syntax the serial function may need so it can compile.

do you have any experience with serial?
also what does make PYCharm better than VS? (though i'm kinda certain that VS is not the best program for Python by the amount of dumb non logic errors i had to fix^^)

Comment: So if your print statement is not giving anything, it is expected that serial connection will fail because the variable `port` does not have anything in it. PyCharm is better because it is made one and only for Python, not need to add anything special and it keeps things simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don´t find any COM port, so `port` is never defined.
I rework your code and this version works for me (replace `USB` with your keyword).

```
import serial, os, time, serial.tools.list_ports

# Get the COM port
Ports = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

if(len(Ports) == 0):
    print("[ERROR] No COM ports found!")
    exit()

TargetPort = None
for Port in Ports:
    StringPort = str(Port)
    print("[INFO] Port: {}".format(StringPort))
    if("USB" in StringPort):
        TargetPort = StringPort.split(" ")[0]
        print("[INFO] Use {}...".format(TargetPort))

if(TargetPort is None):
    print("[ERROR] No target COM port found!")
    exit()

# Open the COM port
ser = serial.Serial(TargetPort, 9600, timeout = 0)
if(ser.isOpen() == False):
    ser.open()

while(True):
    try:
        line = ser.readline()
        if (line):
            print (cmd)
            #os.system(cmd)
    except:
        pass

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: it works! thank you so much for your work!

I'm not quite sure what you mean by Keyword, what would i replace "USB" with? just anything I want or something specific?

Comment: You can replace `USB` with a keyword to identify your USB connection. So if your USB connection for the arduino is called `COM X - Arduino xy` in the windows device manager you can replace the `USB` with `Arduino` to filter the specific COM port for the arduino (for the case that the COM port number change after a reboot).

Comment: alright! well windows only recognizes it as USB serial device, so i will keep it that way :D

Comment: I have in mind that the Arduino use an FTDI USB/Serial bridge. So if you want you can change the name with FTProg von FTDI :)

Comment: two last questions in case you also know about .exe files (if you don't i will happily ask somebody else! you have helped me so much already!):

1: when i try packaging this into an .exe file and i run it, it just closes right away instead of keeping the wile loop running.

2: and lastly i would like to close the program after the video is launched. in visual studio `sys.exit()` and `exit()` wouldnt do anything if i put them right behind my `os.system(cmd)`

Comment: You can add a console input to keep the terminal open. Add this and create an executable to visualize the program error.
The `exit` is only executed when the `os.system` call has finished.

Comment: When I try this code in raspberry pi, it selects the right port (ttyUSB2) but keeps on waiting for the signal does any one know where am I going wrong.